# Android - ListView with items that fill an entire screen?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am doing a simple Quiz application that has several questions that the user answers. A question would be an item in the list but it would need to occupy the entire screen. When the user answers he would swipe his fingers over the screen to go to the next/previous question.

Can this be done with a build-in view/method? I hope I am being clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can! What you need is the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), it is available as a part of the [compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html). This is a class which allows you to create several pages and scroll between them. These pages can be created using [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). [This blog post on horizontal swiping](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) has the basic information on how to accomplish what you need, you can also have a look at the [examples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Probably a [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) is appropriate, which can handle swiping through several items. It does not only work for pictures :).